# How to manipulate a 3D array to convert from cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, cartesian-coordinates, spherical-coordinate

So I'm new to Python and I'd like to convert a 3D-array containing cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates. I have done this function that calculates the conversion:

```
def cart2sph(x, y, z):
   xy = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) # sqrt(x² + y²)
    
   x_2 = x**2
   y_2 = y**2
   z_2 = z**2

   r = np.sqrt(x_2 + y_2 + z_2) # r = sqrt(x² + y² + z²)

   theta = np.arctan2(y, x) 

   phi = np.arctan2(xy, z) 

   return r, theta, phi
```

However, if I have a random array (N,N,N), such as

```
N = 3   
array = np.random.rand(N, N, N).astype(dtype=np.float16)
```

And pass the x, y and z coordinates to my function to convert from cartesian to spherical

```
x = np.asarray(array_np)[:,0].astype(dtype=np.float16)

y = np.asarray(array_np)[:,1].astype(dtype=np.float16)

z = np.asarray(array_np)[:,2].astype(dtype=np.float16)

sphere_coord = cart2sph(x,y,z)
```

I keep getting wrong conversion results. I've tried different approaches but still couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I am not sure how `N, N, N` is related to `x, y, z`. I would expect an `N, 3` or `3, N` array of coordinates, or a meshgrid defining the three axes

Comment: Please post a coherent [mcve] and show what you expect vs what's coming out

Comment: I second that your data generation is a little off. You want an array of N points, each point with three coordinates x, y and z. Therefore your array should have shape (N, 3) since you are using your columns to differentiate variables in the code you posted. By the way, don't worry about the downvote. Some people are sticklers for rules without the ability to reason when they make sense. The error in your code was obvious, as was the effort you put into your question.

Comment: I understand now, @rocksNwaves! Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked the function with a unique (x, y, z) and it seems to be converting to (r, theta, phi) just fine.

I think your problem is on how are you getting the random (x, y, z). Maybe try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def cart2sph(x, y, z):
   xy = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) # sqrt(x² + y²)
    
   x_2 = x**2
   y_2 = y**2
   z_2 = z**2

   r = np.sqrt(x_2 + y_2 + z_2) # r = sqrt(x² + y² + z²)

   theta = np.arctan2(y, x) 

   phi = np.arctan2(xy, z) 

   return r, theta, phi

N = 3   
array_np = np.random.rand(N).astype(dtype=np.float16)
print('array_np:')
print(array_np)

x = np.asarray(array_np)[0].astype(dtype=np.float16)

y = np.asarray(array_np)[1].astype(dtype=np.float16)

z = np.asarray(array_np)[2].astype(dtype=np.float16)

sphere_coord = cart2sph(x,y,z)

print('\nCartesian:')
print('x',x,'\ny',y,'\nz',z)

print('\nSpherical:')
print(sphere_coord)
```

Output:

> array_np: [0.2864 0.938 0.9243]
>
> Cartesian: x 0.2864 y 0.938 z 0.9243
>
> Spherical: (1.3476626409849026, 1.274, 0.8150028593437515)

Comment: Alright, that's the test I've done before to check if my conversion was right. But how do I convert a 3D array?

Comment: You should read what @rocksNwaves  answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68308053/how-to-manipulate-a-3d-array-to-convert-from-cartesian-coordinates-to-spherical/68308668?noredirect=1#comment120725869_68308053

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by a 3D array (for me a 3D array is just one (x, y, z)). 

Is it three (x, y, z) ternary values?

Comment: Oh, I see now what was my mistake. I was ratiocinating wrong :-)